# Can I use an IP-list include file for iptable blacklisting?

Tags: linux, security, iptables, bash, blocking

I would like to block all countries except mine in iptables, that is a list with about 100.000 Entries.

How can I define this blacklist file in a script, so iptables blocks all those IP ranges?

Maybe I can use: http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/ that provides lists in the form

```
117.55.192.0/20
117.104.224.0/21
119.59.80.0/21
121.100.48.0/21
...
```

I want to be able to change the **blacklistfile** easily without having to change the iptables-script.

Comment: This is usually a bad idea. What are you _really_ wanting to do?

Comment: It would take ages to load, a better approach would be to DENY by default and ACCEPT for the of your country. Just remember that the ips change continuously, so an ip that is from Deutschland today, might be Greek tomorrow, also new ips are assigned every day.

Comment: i think this script is quite useful: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/block-entier-country-using-iptables/

Comment: Wouldn't it be already really effective, if I block the biggest networks with /8 at the mask? Then I would have only 100 rules and would block 1.6 Billion IPs already ;)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `ipset` I think this is exactly what you are looking for. [ipset extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#ipset)

Comment: sounds good, but how do i set this up on ubuntu 12.04.1? this seems, like what i need, but i get errors installing it without the (in 12.04 removed) package ipset-source: http://www.jsimmons.co.uk/2010/06/08/using-ipset-with-iptables-in-ubuntu-lts-1004-to-block-large-ip-ranges/

Comment: I asked another question for that: http://serverfault.com/questions/427308/howto-install-ipset-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Are you sure ? I installed ipset on my 12.04 without any problem. https://gist.github.com/3720382

Answer (score 1):

Blocking by country is certainly a very bad idea but there is a [geoip](http://people.netfilter.org/peejix/geoip/) module for Netfilter which is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: Has anyone tried this lately and any experiences with it?