# Howto use ipset and iptables on Ubuntu 12.04 to block lots of IPs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

I would like to use this tutorial:
http://www.jsimmons.co.uk/2010/06/08/using-ipset-with-iptables-in-ubuntu-lts-1004-to-block-large-ip-ranges/

In Ubuntu 12.04 the package ipset-source is removed from the repository I guess that's why I only  get an error when I try installing it like this:

```
apt-get install module-assistant ipset
m-a a-i ipset
```

How would I do that in Ubuntu precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do something wrong. That article is not up to date because it's about 10.04 LTS. Now you can just issue

```
sudo apt-get install ipset
```

I've just installed ipset on my 12.04 without any problem. Take a look at my install log https://gist.github.com/3720382

Comment: i did that too, and there were no errors either. but don't I have to build and install the kernel module anymore?

Comment: ok, there was no error installing it, just errors on that tutorial at jsimmons

Comment: I found an example here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/ipset.8.html like this: ipset create foo bitmap:ip range 192.168.0.0/16; ipset add foo 192.168.1/24; ipset test foo 192.168.1.1; is that all i need to change the script on  http://www.jsimmons.co.uk/2010/06/08/using-ipset-with-iptables-in-ubuntu-lts-1004-to-block-large-ip-ranges/ ?

Comment: Yes exactly this is what you need to do

Comment: how would i create a group then, than can consist of thousands of ip-ranges? ipset create foo bitmap:ip range 0.0.0.0/8 ?

Comment: or `ipset create foo bitmap:ip range 0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: I think that could be dangerous! cause my server crashes, if I add a list to 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 2):

This is how [this tutoriall at jsimmons](http://www.jsimmons.co.uk/2010/06/08/using-ipset-with-iptables-in-ubuntu-lts-1004-to-block-large-ip-ranges/) works on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install ipset

# enter the countrycode that you dont want to block here (for example de for Germay):
DONTBLOCK=de

# download the zonefiles into /tmp/zones/
cd /tmp
wget http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/all-zones.tar.gz
mkdir zones
cd zones
tar -xzvf ../all-zones.tar.gz
# remove the zone you want to keep:
rm /tmp/zones/$DONTBLOCK.zone

FOLDER=/etc/zoneipblock/
mkdir $FOLDER
BLOCKLIST=$FOLDER"non_$DONTBLOCK.zone_blocklist"
cat /tmp/zones/*.zone > $BLOCKLIST

#if you want to block only the biggest blocks, use the short list:
BLOCKLIST_SHORT="$BLOCKLIST"_short
cat $BLOCKLIST |grep /8>$BLOCKLIST_SHORT
cat $BLOCKLIST |grep /9>>$BLOCKLIST_SHORT
cat $BLOCKLIST |grep /10>>$BLOCKLIST_SHORT
cat $BLOCKLIST |grep /11>>$BLOCKLIST_SHORT
cat $BLOCKLIST |grep /12>>$BLOCKLIST_SHORT

IPS=$(cat $BLOCKLIST_SHORT)

exit

#TODO: create the list with the right command
#ipset create feckof ...
ipset --create feckoff bitmap:ip range [fromip-toip|ip/cidr]

for i in $IPS; do
ipset add feckof $i
done

iptables -A INPUT -m set –set feckoff src -j DROP
```

Thats the script, nearly finished, only the create statement for the feckof list is missing.

can someone add this in a comment please?

Comment: One problem i could see is that on my RedHat like systems upon bootup, NAT has to be brought up before iptables and ipset has to be configured before iptables.  So if ipset hangs, you might have a NAT with no firewall.

Comment: The above iptables command did not work for me, but the following did:      iptables -A OUTPUT -m set --match-set feckof src,dst -j DROP

Comment: Unfortunately, most lists at http://www.ipdeny.com seem to be empty. Not sure if it's a temporary problem or if the site is abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario just download the source from [Ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/install.html) and compile it manually.

```
wget http://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset-6.13.tar.bz2
tar xvfj ipset-6.13.tar.bz2
cd ipset-6.13
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

For more info check the `README` or `INSTALL` or run `./configure --help` for some exotic options.

Comment: thx, but apt-get is just fine ;)

Comment: haha that's too easy :))

Comment: `ipset` has come a looong way... I remember having to compile from source. Ubuntu is getting more enjoyable, lately :)